# MySQL - how to create ownerless View?

Tags: mysql

We have a production environment, a staging environment, and a test environment. The username is the same on all three databases for the MySQL user, but when I create a VIEW on production, when the production DB gets dumped to the various test servers, the VIEWs (or FUNCTIONs) are unusable because USER@productionIP doesn't exist. Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do several things:

- if you have a .sql dump you can raplace productionIP with testIP with a text editor
- you can update the production view definer as 'USER@localhost', in that way you can use the dump in each enviroment
- you can create on test enviroment a USER@productionIP

Comment: Isn't there a way to create a VIEW or FUNCTION that works for all users?